# how to delete telegram service message after 60 sec sent by BOT

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

i want to delete service message sent by bot after 60 sec.
bot already admin of the group, and i use php for it

when i send
`https://api.telegram.org/bottoken/sendMessage?chat_id=chatid&text=hello this is bot`
it returns nothing as it sent from bot

but return parameters like message id, text when a user send a message in a group but nothing when bot sends any message

any way to delete the service message after 60 sec or something like rose bot or groupbutler in php command

Answer (score 1):

The JSON response to your request will contain the JSON serialized message resulting from your request. Citing the [docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage):

> On success, the sent Message is returned.

Comment: can i know how to delete after 60 sec for service message as their is nothing returns when bot send a message(as i said previously it returns from webhook when user send any message in group )   $key = array(

    "message_auto_delete_time" => 3,
    
);

$keyen = json_encode($key);


$url= "https://api.telegram.org/bottoken/sendMessage?chat_id=chatid&text=hello&entities=$keyen";

file_get_contents($url)